# Salesforce Mobile SDK iOS - SFNativeRestAppDelegate

Tags: ios, salesforce, salesforce-mobile-sdk

Using the Salesforce Mobile SDK iOS framework template

```
The SFNativeRestAppDelegate state tat you should override:
- (UIViewController*)newRootViewController {..}
```

Returning a UIViewController - the template works with a UITableViewController, but when using     a UISplitViewController I get the following error:

'Application tried to present a Split View Controllers modally

Answer (score 1):

The Salesforce framework is showing the rootViewController as modal. The solution is to override - (void)setupNewRootViewController from SFNativeRestAppDelegate.

Salesforce framwork developer gave me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot present Split View Controllers modally, it was designed to always be a root view controller.